# Crear variables globales en Python

Tags: python, variables-globales

Yo soy bastante nuevo con la sintaxis de Python en particular **como crear global, nonlocal y local variables y como declararlas sin errores de sintaxis**.

Por ejemplo en el programo siguiente, tengo

```
# Estamos creando el juego de Piedra, papel o tijera

import random

userScore = 0;
cpuScore = 0;
global noChoice = True;



# result viene de que los jugadores han elegido, no muestro esta parte
# porque no es necesario por el tema de errores de sintaxis por las variables
def result(userChoice, cpuChoice):



# Traimos de saber lo que el usuario quiere elegir como estrategia
def start():
    while (noChoice):
        try:
            userChoice = int(raw_input("Make a move: Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3"));
        except ValueError: "That's definitely not a number"
        if userChoice == {1,2,3}:
            global noChoice = False;
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."

    cpuChoice = random.getInt();

start()
```

Este da el resultado siguiente:

```
:~$ python pFC.py
  File "pFC.py", line 7
    global noChoice = True;
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

He utilizado `global` sino dice que he declaro la variable demasiado pronto.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'noChoice' referenced before assignment
```

---

He utilizado lo que me han aconsejado, pero el error permanece

```
# Estamos creando el juego de Piedra, papel o tijera

import random

user_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
global no_choice = True



# result viene de que los jugadores han elegido, no muestro esta parte
# porque no es necesario por el tema de errores de sintaxis por las variables
def result(user_choice, cpu_choice):


# Traimos de saber lo que el usuario quiere elegir como estrategia
def start():
    #Hey Python! Vamos a utilizar una variable global!
    global no_choice
    while (no_choice):
        try:
            user_choice = int(raw_input("Make a move: Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3"))
        except ValueError: "That's definitely not a number"
        if user_choice == {1,2,3}:
            global no_choice = False
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."

    cpuChoice = random.getInt();

start()
```

Answer (score 13):

Bien, creo que empezaré recomendándote que le des una ojeada al [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) que es la guía de estilos que debes de tener en cuenta al usar Python.

Por ejemplo, para la definición de variables no se usa [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) ni tampoco es necesario usar `;` al finalizar cada sentencia:

```
userScore = 0;
cpuScore = 0;
```

Se debería convertir en:

```
user_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
```

Ten en cuenta que el PEP 8 es solo una *guía*, si prefieres seguir haciéndolo a tu manera, está bien.

---

Ahora sí, con respecto a las variables globales en tu código. El problema es que lo estás haciendo de manera incorrecta.

Considera este script que vamos a ir creando en forma progresiva:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Es una variable global disponible para cualquier función definida dentro de
# este script
no_choice = True

def start():
    # No es necesario indicar que quieres usar la variable global
    print "El valor de no_choice es:", no_choice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

El resultado sería:

```
El valor de no_choice es: True
```

Observa que no estoy usando `global` ya que el uso de `global` **no es para definir** una variable global (a pesar de que te sientas tentado a hacerlo por su nombre).

Ahora, imagina que quieres modificar la variable `no_choice`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Es una variable global disponible para cualquier función definida dentro de
# este script
no_choice = True

def start():
    # No es necesario indicar que quieres usar la variable global
    print "El valor de no_choice es:", no_choice
    # Quiero negar el valor de no_choice (cambiarla a False)
    no_choice = not no_choice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Esto va a generar un error:

```
El valor de no_choice es:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    start()
  File "test.py", line 9, in start
    print "El valor de no_choice es:", no_choice
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'no_choice' referenced before assignment
```

Python no sabe a que variable `no_choice` te refieres y asume que debe ser una dentro del alcance de la función `start`, pero no la encuentra y arroja el error `UnboundLocalError` (que ocurre cuando estás tratando de usar una variable que no ha sido definida).

Ahora, para poder modificarla tenemos que indicarle a Python que estamos queriendo usar la variable global, en este caso sí tenemos que usar `global`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Es una variable global disponible para cualquier función definida dentro de
# este script
no_choice = True

def start():
    # Hey Python, voy a usar una variable global
    global no_choice
    print "El valor de no_choice es:", no_choice
    # Quiero negar el valor de no_choice (cambiarla a False)
    no_choice = not no_choice
    print "Ahora el valor de no_choice es:", no_choice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

El resultado sería:

```
El valor de no_choice es: True
Ahora el valor de no_choice es: False
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para su respuesta muy didáctica! Sin embargo tras modificar, el error permanece...

Comment: Hola @Marine1 actualiza tu código en la pregunta para revisarlo

Answer (score 8):

Por completar las respuestas anteriores, que se han centrado más bien en arreglar tu código, voy a dar una respuesta un poco más genérica que defina qué es cada tipo de variable y en particular explique el `nonlocal` por el que preguntabas que no ha sido tratado en las ortras respuestas.

## local

No existe esta palabra reservada en Python. No puedes "declarar" una variable como local. Se considera local automáticamente **cualquier variable que sea asignada dentro de una función**.

Por ejemplo

```
def test():
    x = 1
    print(x)
```

Por el hecho de que la asignación `x=1` aparezca dentro de la función, (no necesariamente en la primera línea, sino en cualquier parte de la función), la variable `x` ya se considera local.

Naturalmente la asignación debe ocurrir *antes* de intentar usarla pues si lo intentas al revés:

```
def test_mal():
    print(x)
    x = 1
```

cuando intente hacer `print(x)` la variable aún no tiene ningún valor, y te dará el error "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

## global

Una variable global es una que se asigna fuera de las funciones. Al ser global es "visible" por cualquier función que puede utilizar su valor. Ejemplo:

```
x = 0  # Es global por estar fuera de las funciones
def test():
    print(x)
```

Pero hay un potencial conflicto. Si una función intenta *cambiar* el valor de x, con algo como esto:

```
x = 0
def test_mal():
    x = 1
    print(x)
```

entonces, debido a que aparece una *asignación* dentro de la función y de acuerdo con lo explicado en el apartado anterior, la variable `x` se considerará local. Se crea por tanto una nueva variable `x` específica para la función `test()` que impedirá acceder a la variable global del mismo nombre. Aunque `print(x)` mostrará 1, ese es un valor local. Cuando la función termine, dejará de existir. La `x` global seguirá valiendo cero.

Debido a que esta `x` es local, se nos puede plantear exactamente el mismo problema ya visto si la modificamos dentro de la función, pero la intentamos usar *antes* de haberla modificado, así:

```
x = 0
def test_mal():
    print(x)
    x = 1
```

Debido a que *antes siquiera de intentar ejecutar esta función* python ya ha visto que en alguna línea de la misma se asigna un valor a `x`, considerará `x` local. Por lo tanto el primer `print(x)` intentará imprimir la variable local y ya que ésta aún no tiene un valor asignado, se producirá el error.

Para resolver este problema existe la palabra `global` que permite especificarle a Python que, aunque vea una asignación dentro de la función, no cree una nueva variable local, sino que haga uso de la global. Así:

```
x = 0
def test():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 1
```

En este caso, las referencias que ocurren a `x` dentro de la función `test()` acceden a la `x` global, por lo que el código no sólo no da error, sino que cuando la función termine de ejecutarse el valor de la `x` global habrá cambiado.

## nonlocal

Esta palabra existe para un caso muy particular, y es el de funciones anidadas que necesitan acceder a variables que, ni son locales de la propia función anidada, ni son globales, sino que son variables de la función dentro de la cual están anidadas.

Si lo anterior parece un trabalenguas, intentemos ver un ejemplo:

```
x = 0
def test():
    x = 1

    def anidada():
        x = 2
        print(x)

    anidada()
```

¿Qué imprimirá este programa si ejecuto `test()`? ¿Cuánto valdrá la variable global `x` al terminar?

Al ejecutar `test()`, ya que ésta contiene una asignación `x=1` y no ha dicho que se use la `x` global, se crea una nueva variable local para la función `test()`. Podríamos llamarla "test.x" (aunque esta sintaxis no es correcta, ayuda a ver que se trata de una x que "pertenece" a test). A esa se le da el valor 1 (la `x` global sigue valiendo 0)

Seguidamente se define una función anidada, y se invoca la función anidada. Dentro de ella hay una asignación `x=2`, pero ya que no se ha dicho que la `x` sea global, de nuevo se creará una local. Para entendernos llamémosla "test.anidada.x", y a ella se le asigna el valor 2. La global sigue valiendo 0.

Así que se imprimirá un 2 y la global seguirá valiendo 0.

Si quisiéramos que la función `anidada()` modificara el valor de la global, la solución es sencilla y ya la conocemos:

```
x = 0
def test():
    x = 1

    def anidada():
        global x
        x = 2
        print(x)

    anidada()
```

En este ejemplo se sigue creando la variable que habíamos llamado "test.x", pero ya no se crea una "test.anidada.x", sino que el `x=2` actúa sobre la global.

Pero ¿y si quisiéramos desde `anidada()` modificar la `x` local de `test()`? Es decir, de algún modo quiero que `x=2` modifique "test.x".

Para esto es la palabra `nonlocal`:

```
x = 0
def test():
    x = 1

    def anidada():
        nonlocal x
        x = 2
        print(x)

    anidada()
```

Cuando Python ve `nonlocal x` sabe que aunque esa función intente asignar valores a una `x`, no debe crear una variable local para ello. Deberá usar la `x` que esté accesible dentro de su alcance (que será la definida en la asignación `x=1`)

Answer (score 7):

No necesitas la palabra **global** cuando la declaras, porque al estar fuera de la definición de una función automaticamente se vuelve global, pero si necesitas el identificador **global** en las funciones que vayan a modificarla, pero declarandola primero asi:

```
  if userChoice == {1,2,3}:
        global noChoice
        noChoice = False;
        print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Answer (score 3):

Bueno, en cuanto a las recomendaciones y las buenas prácticas, ya lo habrás visto en otras respuestas.

Para responder a tu pregunta, iré mencionando los errores que he notado desde el principio
Primero:

```
no_choice = True
```

Al declarar una variable no necesitas usar global, solo la declaras por su nombre, su situación como global o local, es implícita(global en ese caso).

Luego, al usar "global no_choice" dentro del **def start()** creas una referencia a la variable fuera del def (osea en el ambito global), eso a mi parecer es "legal"

Sobre el "if user_choice == {1,2,3}". Este ultimo posiblemente te dará un error si lo usas de ese modo, ya que lo ingresado por el usuario solo será uno de esos numeros, no una lista con todos.
Te recomiendo cambiarlo por:

```
if user_choice in {1,2,3}
```

En cuanto al "global no_choice=False", mejor lo dejas como:

```
no_choice=False
```

Con el "global" que pusiste al principio del def start(), ya le hiciste saber al python cual querías modificar, no hace falta usarlo de nuevo.

Por ultimo, la variable cpuChoice, si vas a usarla fuera del def luego, te recomendaría declararla con las demás
Pero si quieres declarar una variable global desde dentro del algún def:

```
>>>globals().update({"nombre_de_variable":3}) #el 3 es el valor de ejemplo, puedes usar un string u otra variable
>>>nombre_de_variable
3
```

Esto declara la variable accesible desde cualquier sitio (global)

Sobre el random, el def para seleccionar un número al azar es randint(minimo,maximo), así que imagino usarás:

```
globals().update({"cpuChoice":random.randint(1,3)})
```

o en caso de que no planearas crear la variable global

```
cpuChoice=random.randint(1,3)
```

## Resumo:

Para usar la informacion de una variable global no necesitas usar "global", solo para editarla, y si acaso vas a editarla primero

```
global variable
variable="nuevo valor" # no puedes hacer ambas en una sola linea
```

o la otra opcion que también declara la variable en caso de que no exista.

```
globals().update({"variable":"nuevo valor"})
```

Para crear y modificar variables locales no necesitas usar ninguna palabra especial.
Y en caso de las nonlocal, solo las usas cuando metes un def dentro de otro, no lo recomiendo, pero si quieres un ejemplo https://www.smallsurething.com/a-quick-guide-to-nonlocal-in-python-3/

Saludos y buena suerte n_n

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que estás usando una sintaxis incorrecta para usar la palabra reservada 'global'

Esta sería la sintaxis correcta:

```
# Estamos creando el juego de Piedra, papel o tijera

import random

userScore = 0;
cpuScore = 0;
noChoice = True #Estás estableciendo un 'global' en una fila sin tabulador, cuando escribas una variable sin ningún tabulador, será una variable global automáticamente



# result viene de que los jugadores han elegido, no muestro esta parte
# porque no es necesario por el tema de errores de sintaxis por las variables
def result(userChoice, cpuChoice):



# Traimos de saber lo que el usuario quiere elegir como estrategia
def start():
    while (noChoice):
        try:
            userChoice = int(raw_input("Make a move: Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3"));
        except ValueError: "That's definitely not a number"
        if userChoice == {1,2,3}:
            global noChoice #Primero indicas que es una variable global antes de asignarla, de ahí que te devuelva el error en el igual.
            noChoice = False
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."

    cpuChoice = random.getInt();

start()
```