# Obtener el valor asignado en un Combobox en otro método

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, variables-globales

quiero utilizar el valor asignado a un combobox en otro método. He creado una variable global para este combobox, pero por otros post veo que no es la solución acertada en python:

El código es el siguiente:

```
global comboAnio

def ventanaReubicar():
    miFrame = Frame()
    miFrame.pack(fill="both")
    #miFrame.config(bg="white")
    miFrame.config(width="600", height="500")

    anio=Label(miFrame, text="Ano:")
    anio.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    comboAnio = Combobox(miFrame, values=("2018", "2017"))
    comboAnio.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=5)
    comboAnio.current(0)

    #Boton de busqueda
    botonBuscar=Button(miFrame, text="Buscar", 
command=metodo2)
    botonBuscar.grid(row=4, column=10, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=5)


def metodo2():
     generarDatos(comboAnio.get())
```

Y el error obtenido es el siguiente:

**NameError: name 'comboAnio' is not defined**

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el valor de ese combobox con valor en un método en otro?

Comment: `global` no se usa para definir la variable como global, toda variable definida a nivel de módulo es global. `global` sirve para especificar dentro del método o función que se trate esa variable como global y no cree una local del mismo nombre cuando intentemos una asignación. `global comboAnio` va **dentro de la función que la use como tal, no cuando la defines**.

Comment: Adriana bienvenida a [es.so], he marcado la pregunta como duplicada, porque tu problema es básicamente el mismo que el mostrado en [Crear variables globales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10768/15089), mírate las respuestas a esa pregunta. Si aún así te surge alguna duda solo comenta. Un saludo.