# Usar una variable de fuera del código

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa en python y quiero declarar las variables nada más empezar, para tenerlo todo organizado, pero me he dado cuenta que si en el código tengo un bucle o una cosa así e intento usar una variable que no esté declarada ahí, no me funciona.

Querría saber si hay alguna forma de "invocar" la variable en el trozo de código que necesito, sin tener que volver a escribir todo el contenido de la misma.

Gracias!

Comment: Publica tu código para entender mejor tu pregunta: ¿qué tienes? ¿qué deseas?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo no se entiende, pero sospecho que tu problema es que intentas asignar (cambiar  el valor) una de esas variables globales desde dentro de una función. Mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/280089/7123) para aclarar conceptos.

Comment: Por otro lado, el uso de variables globales se considera mala práctica. Deberías usar funciones puras que no modifiquen ninguna variable externa a ellas, y que por tanto lo hagan todo mediante parámetros y resultados retornados. O bien plantearte usar programación orientada a objetos y entonces todas las funciones (métodos) de un objeto podrían compartir las variables (atributos) de ese objeto.

Comment: Necesitas comprender el ámbito de visibilidad de las variables, entre otras cosas. Te sugiero leer el [Tutorial de pyton -del sitio oficial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/index.html).