# Como llamaría a esta variable local desde una función anidada

Tags: python, funciones, variables, variables-globales

Estaba haciendo un main() y dentro he ubicado una función esa función ha llamado a una variable dentro del main() como llamaría ha esa variable para poder editarla en la función anidada. Estoy utilizando python
Pseudocódigo:

```
def main ():
  var1=0
  def funcion_anidada():
    #esto de abajo no seria global por que es local
    global var1
    var1+=1
  #demas codigo
```

Comment: `nonlocal var1`

Comment: Mas detalles [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/280089/7123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el uso de la variable como global, lo tendrías que declarar fuera de tu función principal, lo que te permitirá su uso como preguntaste

```
var1 = 0
def main():
    def funcion_anidada():
        global var1 #Llamando a la variable global
        var1 += 1
        #podrías usar un return con el valor de var1
    funcion_anidada() #Tienes que invocar tu función anidada
main()
print(var1) # Resultado = 1, al ser global te permite el uso fuera de la función principal
```

Si declaras el valor dentro de la función utiliza la palabra nonlocal para que te permita el uso de la variable que ha sido declarada por la función padre

```
def main():
    var1 = 0
    def funcion_anidada():
        nonlocal var1 #Llamando a la variable de la función padre
        var1 += 1
    funcion_anidada() #Tienes que invocar tu función anidada 
    print(var1) #se imprime aquí, ya que fuera de la función no existe
main() # Resultado = 1
```